# How to delete leading characters until 1-9 are met

Tags: regex, bash

I have time spans in the format of

```
00h29m37s
01h31m24s
```

How to delete all leading characters until `[1-9]` is hit? For the above examples, the desired output is

```
29m37s
1h31m24s
```

We don't need to worry about `00h00m00s` since it doesn't occur

Comment: So you simply want to delete leading zeroes from each line? Please post your own attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Not just `0`, please see the 1st example, `00h` is deleted @user1934428

Comment: I see. And what is the expected output for `00h00m08s`? This should then be `8s`? And `00h00m00s` would simply erase everything. Right?

Comment: Yes. In reality I don't have `00h00m00s` instances

Comment: Please add this information to your question, not as a comment, because it is important for any solution provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat input
00h29m37s
01h31m24s
$ sed 's/^[^1-9]*//' input
29m37s
1h31m24s
```

The `[^1-9]` matches all characters that are *not* 1 thru 9.  The `*` makes that match the longest such string of characters.  `s` only operates on the first match of the regex, so it effectively deletes the leading string of characters that do not match 1-9.

The `^` anchors the match to the beginning of the string, but note that it is not necessary.  Without the `^`, the `[^1-9]*` will match the leading string of length zero, so a string like `31m04s` will not be edited.  This is a bit confusing and worthy of mention.  If you did want to edit `31m04s` to remove the first longest string of characters that do not match 1 thru 9, you could do `sed 's/[^1-9]\+//'` or (if using a `sed` that does not support `+`)  `sed 's/[^1-9][^1-9]*//'`

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F 'h' '+$1 > 0 { print +$1FS$2;next } { print $2 }' file
```

Set the field separator to "h" and then when the first "h" separated field is greater than 1, print the field, stripping out the leading 0 (+$1) along with the field separator and the second field, then skip to the next record. If the first field is equal to 0, print the second field only.